# $.each and animation confusion

Tags: jquery

I am expecting when I go

```
$.each($(something).find(something), function(){
   $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

then for each matching element I get a second of delay before it is gone. but what I get is a second of delay and then it all fades out. its 3am and I can't think. please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, call it with a jQuery object as a parameter:

```
function fadeAll(elems) {
    var i=-1;
    function next() {
        i = i+1;
        if (i < elems.length)
            $(elems[i]).delay(1000).fadeOut(next);
    }
    next();
}
```

You can see it at work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wMtLs/).

Comment: how would you use this with animate instead of fadeOut? as if you go for example animate({something : 'its value'}, next());
it jumps again right to the end

Comment: @XGreen: That should say `next` instead of `next()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question right, you want things to fade out over the duration of a second? If so, what you want is `$(this).fadeOut(1000);`, which sets the duration of a fade; doing the `delay(1000)` just waits a second *before* it starts your `fadeOut()` action.

Comment: Also, this doesn't need to be iterated: this should work `$(something).find(somethingelse).fadeOut(1000)` -- do it all at once (no `each` required)

Comment: what i want is delay 1sec -> elem[0] fades out -> delay 1 sec -> elem[1] fades out.

Comment: now thinking about it each fade out function could be a call back for the fadeout of the prev element but probably it will look like the worst code ever written in history

Comment: In that case, you want to run animations *sequentially*. refer to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218152/how-can-i-animate-multiple-elements-sequentially-using-jquery

Comment: that is not very nice is it? I mean I am dealing with unknown number of elements here and they could be a lot

Comment: Yeah, you might be looking at making a new plugin for something like this (or searching for one)

Answer (score 1):

This should be the basic idea:

```
var set = $(something).find(something);
var delayFade = function(){
     $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, nextDelayFade);
};
var i = 0;
var nextDelayFade = function()
{
  if(i < set.length)
  {
    $(set[i++]).each(delayFade);
  }
};
nextDelayFade();
```