# Animate elements sequentially using CSS3 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

I'm a beginner to jQuery (and CSS3 and everything else for that matter) and am wondering how to automatically animate three different elements (images, in this case) so that they appear one after the other in a sequence - #1, #2, #3 - when the page loads. Here's my CSS:

```
img#element3 {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    top:25px;
}

img#element2 {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    top:270px;
    left:60px;
    margin:10px 0;
}

img#element1 {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    top:328px;
    left:70px;
    margin:10px 0;
}
```

For the jQuery, I tried to modify the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218152/how-can-i-animate-multiple-elements-sequentially-using-jquery) but it's not working. Here's what I did for jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(handler)
    $("#element3").animate({opacity: "1"}, "slow", function() {
    $("#element2").animate({opacity: "1"}, "slow", function() {
    $("element1").animate({opacity: "1"}, "slow", function() {
    });
});
});
```

Is there a way to do this using just CSS3 animations or transitions? If not, what's the proper way to do so using jQuery, and how do you specify orders and delays to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could not do the staged animation with CSS alone.

Your code has a lot of syntax problems. You can consult your error console or use a tool such as [JSLint](http://jslint.com).

I'd probably use...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element3").fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $("#element2").fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $("#element1").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/krsv7/).

Comment: Oh wow, hadn't used JSLint before...thanks! +1 for the Fiddle too.

Answer (score 2):

A little cleaner if you use a class, or a multiple selector with `.each()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element3,#element2,#element1").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(600*i).animate({opacity: "1"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

...or if the order is reversed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( $("#element3,#element2,#element1").get().reverse() ).each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(600*i).animate({opacity: "1"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 good alternate approach. But don't forget to fix up the `ready()` code :)

Comment: @alex: Yeah, I got that, but I messed up by not using `.delay()`! Fixed. :o)

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly possible with css3 animations, unlike the marked answers says.

To build on his solutions:

use `keyframes` and `animation-delay` to fire animations one after the other.

```
@keyframes 'fadein' {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

just increase the `animation-delay` on each element to be the equal to the sum of the previous elements `animation-duration` values.

and of course make sure to use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) with a js fallback!

[here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dwick/krsv7/9/) the complete solution for webkit; apply other browser prefixes as needed.

Comment: Isn't it possible only if the animation loops? Otherwise, the elements return to their opacity:0 at the end. The second and third element can have a delay OR a persisted end state with "forwards", but not both, and in this case they seem to need both.