# Writing a global animation queue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

Adding a sequence of animations to a single dom element using jQuery is extremely easy. jQuery queues everything up nicely for me and I basically don't have to do anything.

However making a sequence of animations over a number of elements (eg pictureDiv fades out, then demographicsDiv fades in) is much harder. I've written a plugin type thing to make it easier as below:

```
var something.createAnimationQueue = function () {

    // jQuery queues up animations on each dom element (/ jquery object)
    // We want to queue up animations over different dom elements so 
    // use a jquery object on a blank element
    var animationQueue = $({});

    return {
        add: function (animationFunctionContext, animationFunction) {
            var args = $.makeArray(arguments).slice(2);
            animationQueue.queue(function (next) {
                $.when(animationFunction.apply(animationFunctionContext, args)).done(next)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Which is used thusly

```
        var animationQueue = something.createAnimationQueue();

        animationQueue.add(pictureDiv, pictureDiv.fadeOut, 'slow');
        animationQueue.add(demographicsDiv, demographicsDiv.fadeIn, 'slow');
```

My questions are:

1) Have I missed something? Is there an easier way of doing this that I didn't know about.

2) If not, is there a way to avoid passing pictureDiv and pictureDiv.fadeOut to the animationQueuer? (I tried and couldn't think of one)

Thanks!

Comment: And I assume you want to do this because the built-in callbacks would be too verbose?

Comment: @Shmiddty Yep, just chaining a couple of things using callbacks or promises is fine, but if you are doing, say, 20 then things get ugly very quickly.

Comment: One problem is that you can't call callbacks for some of the animations, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi @Tebb. Are you saying that "$.when(animationFunction.apply(animationFunctionContext, args)).done(next)" doesn't work as you would expect? If not I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: I haven't tested this code, but if I want, for example, to make an alert between `animationQueue.add(pictureDiv, pictureDiv.fadeOut, 'slow');` and `animationQueue.add(demographicsDiv, demographicsDiv.fadeIn, 'slow');`, how would I do it?

Comment: Hi @Tebb. jquery can handle functions that aren't deferred objects, it just returns straight away. I tried the code out that you wanted, and bizarrely window.alert doesn't have the apply method. I don't really understand this, but you can get round it by using the code below (ie passing in a function which does have the apply method, which then calls window.alert).
  animationQueue.add(window, function () {window.alert('hello');});

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I animate multiple elements sequentially using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218152/how-can-i-animate-multiple-elements-sequentially-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using .apply and reassigning `this`, you could simply use

```
var animationQueue = something.createAnimationQueue();

animationQueue.add(pictureDiv, $.fn.fadeOut, 'slow');
animationQueue.add(demographicsDiv, $.fn.fadeIn, 'slow');
```

And if you really wanted to, you could turn that into a string:

```
var something.createAnimationQueue = function () {

    // jQuery queues up animations on each dom element (/ jquery object)
    // We want to queue up animations over different dom elements so 
    // use a jquery object on a blank element
    var animationQueue = $({});

    return {
        add: function (animationFunctionContext, method) { // <----
            var args = $.makeArray(arguments).slice(2);
            animationQueue.queue(function (next) {
                $.when($.fn[method].apply(animationFunctionContext, args)).done(next) // <----
            })
        }
    }
}

var animationQueue = something.createAnimationQueue();

animationQueue.add(pictureDiv, 'fadeOut', 'slow'); // <----
animationQueue.add(demographicsDiv, 'fadeIn', 'slow'); // <----
```

Note, however, this can't be used for more than just animations now. You could use this with any jQuery method that returns a promise object, such as .ajax, .post, .get, .getJSON, etc. if you used it like you originally had it.

Comment: Couldn't it be taken a step further with just passing in `"fadeOut"` and then `$.fn[animationFunction].apply...`?

Comment: @Shmiddty Yup, I was writing it up, it is now posted.

Comment: Good answer. I thought about $.fn. but it seemed like I was just replacing (say pictureDiv) with something else and I wasn't that excited about it. Referencing the jquery prototype's properties using the string is really neat and I like it, although I'm probably not going to actually use it, in case I want to add non jquery stuff to the queue.