# jquery pause multiple elements?

Tags: jquery, animation, queue, controls

[fxqueues](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/fxqueues) Doesn't seem to work with newer versions of jquery.

I am animating many elements and need to pause / play them.  Simply stringing callbacks will not give me the control I require (readably at least) as stopping an animation requires a reference to the element being animated and there are many many elements.

I've tried to queue animations to a parent div but that doesn't seem to work. Stuff like:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='c1'></div>
    <div class='c2'></div>
    <div class='c3'></div>
    <div class='c4'></div>
</div>

$('#parent')
    .queue(function(){$('.c1').animate({...})});
    .queue(function(){$('.c2').animate({...})});
    .queue(function(){$('.c3').animate({...})});
    .queue(function(){$('.c3').animate({...})});

$('#parent').pause();
$('#parent').clearQueueu();
```

I'm about to play with: [stackoverflow answer for something related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675275/writing-a-global-animation-queue-in-jquery)

is this such a rare need that the jquery team is justified in neglecting this functionality as in [requests like this 1 of the many examples](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7490)? 
OR
is there some other strategy with .promise(), .done(), .defferend(), Callbacks.add()...etc. that I should learn?

Again using callbacks for each animation is cumbersome with many animations and pausing / playing functionality with all those callbacks means my pause function has to have lines for each one of the MANY elements in motion.

```
$('.c1').pause();
$('.c2').pause();
$('.c3').pause();
$('.c4').pause();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the [:animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector help you? You should be able to select all animated elements and stop them.

Comment: that does clean up my pause and start functions!  I think have some timing issues to work through without a global queue... Thank you for the direction!.

Comment: so this isn't working for me because I call functions with timeouts :(.  As i mentioned I have some timing issues to work through.  I think I have to look into control flow, queueing, instead of nesting callbacks and setTimeouts.  Thanks... I'll be back!