# jQuery.fadeOut() - How to apply sequentially to a set of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 'n' buttons

I need to

```
$('BUTTON').fadeOut();
```

... but I'd like to see one button at time disappear..

how to ?

I tried using next, but in the following way ALL disappears in one moment

```
$(".genresButton").first().fadeOut().next().fadeOut()  ;
```

I tried to use fadeOut to fadeOut the next, but I've not inital knowledge of total number of buttons.

I tried using $.each() but without success

*EDIT:*

This is the working solution i choosed:

```
$("body").on('click', '.genresButton',  function(event) {
    $(".genresButton").not($(this)).each(function(index){
        $(this).delay(index * 500).fadeOut(450);
    });

});
```

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) for that:

```
$('BUTTON').each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(index * 500).fadeOut(450);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/exazul/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/exazul/1/edit)

That schedules each button to fade out over the course of 450ms, at 500ms intervals.

`delay` is great for when you're using any of the effects methods. If you ever need to do this with something that isn't part of the effects suite (like `hide`, for instance), you have to do your own `setTimeout`:

```
$('BUTTON').each(function(index) {
    var btn = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        btn.hide();
    }, index * 500);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/exazul/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/exazul/2/edit)

Comment: @realtebo: Yeah, `delay` is handy. Only works with the "effects" methods (like `fadeOut`), not with `hide` and such. With `hide` and such you'd have to do the `setTimeout` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Really basic example, you can chain callback functions:

```
$("#button1").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $("#button2").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $("#button3").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: I've no the total number of element

Answer (score 0):

A generalized cascade avoids having to schedule everything in advance, and is arguably cleaner :

```
function seqFadeOut(jq, i) {
    jq.eq(i).fadeOut(function() {
        seqFadeOut(jq, i+1);
    });
}
seqFadeOut($(".genresButton"), 0);//start the cascade
```

This is effectively @AlexOsborn's approach but for a collection of any size.

*With a little thought, you could even introduce a mechanism for stopping the cascade in mid stream.*

http://jsfiddle.net/zE6nq/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a jQuery queue can be used for this. Although a queue is normally used to sequentially execute animations for a single element, it appears possible to use one for multiple elements. The trick is to use the queue for the body element, like this:

```
$('button').each(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    $('body').queue(function() {
        $button.fadeOut(450, function() { $('body').dequeue(); });
    });
});
```

I got this technique from the answer by @schmunk to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218152/how-can-i-animate-multiple-elements-sequentially-using-jquery).

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/ZtSwv/)