# jQuery Animation with fade in and fade out

Tags: jquery

Looking for some help on creating an effect where various images fade in and fade out. So, I have 3 different images (grouped) that fades in one at a time. For example img-a then img-b then img-c and all 3 images show, pause and the next group of images start. The effect I'm looking to do is similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c6UEm/1/), but instead of the boxing just moving from position a to b I'd like to have them spread across and next to each other. The fiddle comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218152/how-can-i-animate-multiple-elements-sequentially-using-jquery). Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you guys!

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="js-imgFade">
    <div class="slideGroup-one">
        <img class="imgSlide-a" src="//placehold.it/200x200&text=Image 1">
        <img class="imgSlide-b" src="//placehold.it/200x200&text=Image 2">
        <img class="imgSlide-c" src="//placehold.it/200x200&text=Image 3">  
    </div> <!-- /slideGroup-one -->
    <div class="slideGroup-two">
        <img class="imgSlide-a" src="//placehold.it/200x200&text=Image 1">
        <img class="imgSlide-b" src="//placehold.it/200x200&text=Image 2">
        <img class="imgSlide-c" src="//placehold.it/200x200&text=Image 3">  
    </div> <!-- /slideGroup-two -->
</div> <!-- /js-imgFade -->

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

 .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
 }

 [class*="imgSlide-"] {
   background: #e1e1e1;
   border: 1px dashed #ccc;
   margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
   padding: 10px;
}

[class*="imgSlide-"]:first-child {
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this ??

Few `CSS` changes

```
.boxa {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        left: 100px;
        top: 40px; } 
.boxb {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px; }
 .boxc {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        left: 100px;
        top: 160px; }
```

[**Just A try**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/c6UEm/46/)

Comment: No, not exactly. Boxa fades in, then Boxb (next to boxa) and then Boxc (next to boxb) pauses... then the next group of images show doing the same thing as the previous.

Comment: Right. How can I have them faded in one by one?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to say animate. Is it possible to have each box come in from left to right?