# Any Simpler way to Write this jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to this Area of Javascript and jQuery. Aplogize if this is a Silly Question. Hope you'll understand.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fbbtn").click(function(){
        $(".aboutmeshow").hide(function(){
            $(".regtable").hide(function(){
                $('.dndtable').hide(function(){
                    $(".fbtable").slideToggle();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Let me Elaborate the Scenario what i tried here.

This is my UI which has 4 button. When clicking on each button it show its `<div>` element and hides others button `<div>`. and above javascript code is only for one button which i given. Look at the Screenshots below

**User Interface**

[image]

**Click on Feedback Button**

[image]

**Clicking on About me Button hides the feedback button with an effect**

[image]

**Hope this clarifies the Doubt on why am doing this**

Comment: It 's not make any sense to doing next job in callback since you hidding elements instantly, without any timeout

Comment: There is no animation involved, why are you passing the following lines as callbacks?

Comment: Note that the best answer in the duplicate question is the third one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11354378/519413

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fbbtn").click(function(){
            $('.aboutmeshow, .regtable, .dndtable').hide();
            $('.fbtable').slideToggle();
        });
    });

This should to the same.

Comment: Please check the Question Updates  Above on why am doing this. thank you for all the response.